# Stop Xcode from switching to app delegate on SIGABRT

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

Whenever I get a SIGABRT error in my Swift project (if it matters, in this case it was because I was programmatically creating an invalid constraint), Xcode will switch to my app delegate file and highlight the first line of the class declaration as the source of the error.  But there's never any useful information there - if anything, by leaving the code I was last working on, it's more likely to take me away from where the problem is.  Is there any way to change or disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When you crash, Xcode needs to show you something that explains the crash. I don't know of a way to get it not to show you any source at all.

Currently, Xcode will select the lowest frame in the stack of the crashing thread that has debug information, and show the associated source. It seems odd that it is highlighting the class declaration, maybe that's where an implicit init method gets charged to or something?  If this always selects a not relevant place, that seems worth a bug.

But even if the source location is relevant to the crash, I still like to keep my source editor windows from getting repurposed by the debugger.  I do that by setting up a Run Behavior in the Xcode Behavior Preference pane that keeps the debugger in its own tab.  Just set the "Pauses" action of the Running section to   Show a named tab (like "Debugger"), and to show the Debug navigator in that tab.  I also do that in the "Start" action.  Then when the debugger stops I get switched to that tab, and can interact with the Debugger there, leaving my source editor(s) focused on whatever I was looking at when the debugger stopped.